# Is it possible to simultaneously call a method from the children's smart contract by the parent's smart contract?

Tags: solidity, tokens, smart-contract-wallets, binance-smart-chain, smart-contract

I have a smart contract on the BSC network that has created a large number of children and stored the address of each. In the child smart contract, the UUDT token is stored. Also, each child smart contract has a withdrawal method that transfers all balances to a wallet with a fixed address.
Can I have a method in the parent smart contract that calls the withdrawal method of all the children at once and in the form of a transaction? If we can have such a method, how is the gas fee of this transaction calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can batch multiple transactions in one. just make a for loop, that calls each contracts transfer function. I presume all child contract have the same layout? You could do something like:

```
address(child).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw(uint256)", 1000))
```

What this does is it will call child's withdraw function and input 1000 as input.

Regarding the gas, there is a fixed price of 21000 for each transaction + the commands you use in your code, so it is definitely cheaper to batch them and pay the 21000 gas only once.